# Putting records into a dictionary (pymysql)

Tags: python, dictionary, pymysql

I want to put records to dictionary under condition that the value of record in col1 is equal to con. It seems that in this code the condition takes the first record.

```
con = 2
sql = "select col1, col1 from table"
cursor.execute(sql)
results = cursor.fetchall()
dict = {}
for record in self.results:
    if(record[1] == con):
        dict[record [1]] = record[0]
for key, val in dict.items():
    print(key, val)
```

The result is:

```
2
2 1040
2 1050
```

Should be:

```
2 1030
2 1040
2 1050
```

What is the way to get all the records?

Comment: In a dictionary, if you assign a new value to an existing key (`col` in your case) it will replace the old value.

Comment: Why not a `list` of `dict` _**col1, col1**_, this mirrors your DB Layout. **Warning** don't use `dict` as a Variable Name!

Comment: The list works, thank you.